# Implicit differenciation of $u(x,y) := h(x-uy)$

Tags: derivatives

I am trying to verify that $u(x,y) := h(x-uy)$ is the general solution for a PDE. I have obtained it using the method of characteristics for the Cauchy problem:

> $\left\{\begin{matrix}
> uu_{x}+u_{y}=0 \\ 
> u(x,0)=h(x) 
> \end{matrix}\right.$

So I wanted to check if that result is correct, and I have obtained the partial derivatives:

> $u_{x}=(1-yu_{x})h', \hspace{1cm} u_{y}=-(u+yu_{y})h'$

Are these correct? Because I haven't been able to verify if I have solved the PDE.

Comment: yes, they are correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have:
$u_x = (1-u_xy)h'$ (correct) and $u_y=-(u+yu_y)h'$ (almost correct). So, go ahead and solve the equations:

$u_x= \frac{h'}{1+yh'}$

$u_y = \frac{-h'u}{1+h'y}$

Now if you put what we have obatined int your equation it's clearly an identity